# Обобщённая коллекция не принимает элементы

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arraylist, generics

Решил немного поэкспериментировать с `generics` (в частности с ограничениями маски) и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.

Объявил три класса:

```
class SourceClass{
    void print(){
        System.out.println("Am surc");
    }
}

class Child extends SourceClass{

}

class Grandchild extends Child{

}
```

И написал вот такой код:

```
public class MainU {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<? super Child> superGrandList = new ArrayList<>();

        superGrandList.add(new Grandchild());    //Тут всё как надо
        superGrandList.add(new Child());         //Тут тоже

        ArrayList<? extends SourceClass> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();

        sourceList.add(new Grandchild());   //Ошибка!
        sourceList.add(new Child());        //Ошибка!

    }
}
```

Когда пытаюсь добавить элемент в коллекцию `sourceList`, то вылезает ошибка:

```
add capture(<?> extends SourceClass) in ArrayList cannot be applied 
to(Grandchild)
```

Почему так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`? extends SourceClass` говорит о том, что типом элементов списка является "что-то, расширяющее (наследующееся от) `SourceClass`". При этом чем конкретно является это "что-то" - неизвестно. Соответственно, в список нельзя добавить `Child` и `Grandchild`, ибо нет никаких гарантий того, что их типы подходят к типу списка.

С элементом, полученным из списка `? extends SourceClass`, можно работать как с `SourceClass`, потому что чем бы ни являлся тип списка на самом деле, но он точно наследуется от `SourceClass`

---

В первом же случае ситуация обратная.
`? super Child` - типом элементов списка является "что-то, являющееся предком `Child`", поэтому в него можно добавить элемент любого типа, наследующегося от `Child` (так как он по транзитивности гарантированно будет наследоваться и от типа списка, каким бы он ни был).
А вот с полученным элементом из списка можно будет работать только как с `Object`, потому что чем является тип списка - неизвестно, и гарантированно можно говорить только о том, что он наследуется от `Object` (так как все классы наследуются от `Object`)